# Commence vs Begin

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between *commence* and *begin*?
Example Sentence:
**The Harbin International Ice and Snow Sculpture Festival, which has been held since 1985, ________ officially on 5th January each year.**
Should I write *commences* or *begins* in the blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is almost no difference in meaning. Commence is a borrowing from French in the Middle English period, and is used for a more formal starting of something.

In most cases "begin" is the proper word to use, even in formal English, but in this case, describing the official and formal opening of a festival, "commence" would be very appropriate.

Comment: So do I need to use commence here?

Comment: In this case, describing the official and formal opening of a festival, "commence" would be very appropriate.